# Conic section and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, conic-sections

So I was wondering how $x^TAx=0$, where $x=[x\ y\ 1]'$ has anything to do with matrices. I can clearly see $A$ there but how does any property of $A$ (for example invertability, eigen value, or svd decomposition) gives any information about the conic itself. Looking for a good RSS where I can read the relationship from.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections